# What is the Objective C replacement for swift code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

What is the Objective C replacement for below swift code

```
   let words = ["clouds", "rain", "wind"]
   let string = "The rain in Spain"
   let combinedResult = words.contains(where: string.contains)
```

I got this snippet from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-any-words-from-an-array

Comment: Please specify the reason, if you downvote

Comment: I guess the downvotes are because Stack Overflow is not a programming language conversion service platform.

Comment: But then where should we ask such questions? @Raptor

Comment: There's no problem with the question itself, rather with the fact that you didn't show any attempts to solve the problem yourself and ask others to just write the code for you.

Comment: I have tried at my end, but not able to find the solution. That's why I put here

Comment: *I have tried at my end, but not able to find the solution* - how can we know? In the future just post the code you've tried. If you hover on the downvote button you can see its tooltip: *This question does not show any research effort; ...* and this is exactly the case here - you didn't *show* us anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line it's shortcut for:

```
let combinedResult = words.contains {
    string.contains($0)
}
```

And appropriate objc code:

```
NSString* string = @"The rain in Spain";
NSArray* words = @[@"clouds", @"rain", @"wind"];
__block BOOL combinedResult = NO;
[words enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    *stop = combinedResult = [string containsString:obj];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you @iUrii, I will check this solution